# transform variable-content to verbatim-like representation inside a newcommand (used then as optional argument)

Tags: verbatim, xparse, xstring, todonotes

I spend 8 hours in solving this, made some progress but now face the enormous difficulties with verbatim stuff in latex. Any help would be great!

My aim: the `todonotes` package offers an inline option, which however breaks if one wants to use `\listoftodos`, because more complex inline things like equation environments are not suitable somehow for the caption argument.
An easy solution is to set the optional caption argument of `\todo` fix to somthing like `\todo[inline,caption={inline...}]{...}`.
The harder but better solution would be to e.g. cut of the first 20 chars of the inline comment and put it into the caption. This is what I tried and which works *almost*.

Concretely, it already works as long as the cutted version includes no special characters it seems. In the below code you find `%%%%%%%` marking the decisive place. `\StrLeft{\myraw}{10}` works, but `\StrLeft{\myraw}{20}` breaks already.

Additionally I put in some other trials how to make this content verbatime-like. They work outside `\newcommand`, but not inside. I also know about `\NewDocumentCommand{\myverb}{+v}{\texttt{#1}}` from `xparse`, however also here I found no way to achieve what I want.

Looking forward to your help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{verbdef}


% TODO this still does not work for special sequences! kind of escape inbetween?
\newcommand{\MYTODO}[2][]{%
% makes a raw approximation and cut - this must be called within the same newcommand and cannot be outsourced for some reason I do not fully understand:
\scancs[0]\myraw{#2}
%equivalent to:
%\StrExpand[0]{#2}{\h}
%\def\raw{\detokenize\expandafter{\h}}
\StrLeft{\myraw}{10}[\myleft]  %%%%%%% changing this number to for example 20 breaks the code %%%%%%%
%
% this is the essential thing we want:
%\expandafter\verbdef\expandafter\variable\expandafter+\myleft+    %%%breaks immedidiately
%\todo[inline, caption={\string\myleft}, #1]{#2}   %%%breaks immediately
%\todo[inline, caption={\texttt{\myleft}}, #1]{#2}  %%%breaks also for surroundings
\todo[inline, caption={\myleft}, #1]{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\bigskip

\MYTODO[author=me]{ABCDEF}

\MYTODO{%
but what if
\begin{align*}
    x^2
\end{align*}
}


\bigskip
%I tested here some ways to get verbatime output inside a variable, but both do not work in commands
\def\toverb{this works|, but only outside a newcommand.}
\expandafter\verb\expandafter+\toverb+
\expandafter\verbdef\expandafter\fromverb\expandafter+\toverb+
\fromverb

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code for \StrLeft{\raw}{10}]

Comment: Could you explain what you would hope the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to work a verbatim solution, I here use `tokcycle` to cycle through your to-do note input and process it to produce a suitable caption.  The processing to produce the to-do-list caption includes:

1. cat 10, 11, and 12 tokens are echoed into the caption
2. bracing `{}` is transformed into cat-12 `[]`
3. macro names are `\string`ed, however the `\` is replaced with a `/`. A macro counts as only 1 token against the allowed `trunclim`, regardless of how long the macro name is.
4. Catcodes other than 0, 1, 2 ,10 ,11 ,12 are ignored.
5. The total number of *tokens* in the list-of-to-do's caption will not exceed `\thetrunclim - 1`, allowing for the fact that macro names will only count as a single token in this count.
6. In the MWE that follows, `trunclim` is set to `20`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcounter{trunclength}
\def\trunclim{20}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myleft[1]{%
  \setcounter{trunclength}{0}%
  \tokcycle
  {\stepcounter{trunclength}%
   \tctestifnum{\thetrunclength<\trunclim}{%
     \tctestifcatnx A##1{\addcytoks{##1}}{%
     \tctestifcatnx 0##1{\addcytoks{##1}}{%
     }}%
   }{}}%
  {\processtoks{[##1]}}%
  {\stepcounter{trunclength}%
    \tctestifnum{\thetrunclength<\trunclim}{%
    \addcytoks{/}%
    \addcytoks[2]{\expandafter\@gobble\string##1}}{}}%
  {\stepcounter{trunclength}%
    \tctestifnum{\thetrunclength<\trunclim}{\addcytoks{##1}}{}}%
  {#1}%
}
\makeatother
% TODO this still does not work for special sequences! kind of escape inbetween?
\newcommand{\MYTODO}[2][]{%
  \myleft{#2}\todo[inline, caption={\the\cytoks}, #1]{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\bigskip
\MYTODO[author=me]{ABCDEF}
\MYTODO{%
but what if
\begin{align*}
    x^2
\end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `trunclim` is set to 40, this is the result:

[image]